# jMeter stucks after execute a test

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I'm developing a distributed test using jMeter with one slave machine and a simple test script (http request to home):

```
./jmeter -n -t tests/TestPlan.jmx -r -l logs/log_test2.csv -X
```

But when I execute it, jMeter stucks at:

> Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445

I googled and I've find that I can send a shutdown signal using shutdown script, but after execute it jMeter stucks at:

> Command: Shutdown received from /127.0.0.1

This happens too if I execute stoptest.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you tried also stoptest command?

Comment: I'm trying all the commands, without good results

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you try CTRL+C when you see that message?

Comment: I can, but nothing is storaged in my computer and I can't see the test's result.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I execute jMeter specifying rmi hostname, like:

```
./jmeter -n -t tests/TestPlan.jmx -r -l logs/log_test2.csv -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.150.59
```

It runs good.

Answer (score 0):

It usually indicates that JMeter either lacks hardware resources or it is not properly configured for conducting that high load.

1. Make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure you're following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide
3. Make sure you have monitoring of baseline OS and JVM health metrics on the host where JMeter load generator is running, it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) and/or [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)
4. If you still experience issues with test graceful termination you can try adding another load generator host to see if it helps. Be aware that load generators are **independent** so if you define 100 threads under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - each JMeter slave will execute 100 threads. See [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) user manual chapter for more details.
5. Get used to check *jmeter.log* file, normally it contains enough troubleshooting information to get to the bottom of JMeter issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
I've configured jMeter following some links you share. 
I've recently discovered that jMeter stucks when I execute a remote host as a slave; if I execute the test locally it finishes well.